# Lebesgue Measure of a Specific Interval

Tags: real-analysis

The open set in question, it was said, has measure 1.  I am skeptical about this so I thought I should ask in order to be sure.  The open set is the union of sets of the form $(n - 1/2^{n+1}, n + 1/2^{n+1})$ from n=1 to infinity.

Comment: This is not an interval.

Comment: Your set is just a countable union of disjoint sets of measure $\frac{1}{2^{n}}$, so its measure is the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}=1$. It comes form the very definition of "measure": it is a function on a $\sigma$-algebra of sets which vanishes on the empty set and is countably additive, in the sense that measure of a countable union of disjoint sets is the (possibly infinite) sum of their measures - and this is your case. (btw: by "interval") we usually mean a connected subset of a line...)

Comment: Edited for accuracy

Comment: A related/interesting fact I've seen regarding something like this, if we replace $n$ by the $n^{th}$ rational, we can cover the set of rationals using intervals of total length $1$.  Of course you can make that length arbitrarily small.

Comment: @L_b If you copy your comment into the answer box, we'll be able to get this question off the Unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

Since L_b did not copy the comment, I will:

> Your set is just a countable union of disjoint sets of measure $1/2^n$, so its measure is the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/2^n =1$. It comes form the very definition of "measure": it is a function on a $\sigma$-algebra of sets which vanishes on the empty set and is countably additive, in the sense that measure of a countable union of disjoint sets is the (possibly infinite) sum of their measures - and this is your case.